# having issues while accessing Postgresql

Tags: centos7, postgresql

I have installed postgreSql client 9.6 following this link [postgreSql installation](https://yallalabs.com/linux/how-to-install-postgresql-9-6-on-centos-7-rhel-7/) and I am using centos version 7 on Linux.

It got installed successfully but I am getting some problems while accessing that.

I try this.

```
[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ su - postgres
Password:
```

which password need to enter here? I tried postgres which is not working.

I tried this also.

```
[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ sudo -u postgres psql
[sudo] password for xyz:
could not change directory to "/home/xyz": Permission denied
psql (9.6.19)
Type "help" for help.
```

I was able to enter using my password. Is this the right way to enter postgres?

I saw many links on this but I am getting confused finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The home directory of the user xzy is not readable by user postgres, but you start the psql command from there. As a result, you get *permission deny *. Change the directory to some other place before running the sudo:

```
 cd /
 sudo -u postgres psql
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do this from root account. So first become root user:

```
$ sudo -i
#
```

and then:

```
# su - postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1

```
stat -c "%G" .
```

### Step 2

```
sudo usermod -aG <the output from the step 1> postgres
```

[df.tips/t/2063/2](https://df.tips/t/2063/2)